# How to draw text on the desktop in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing

How Would I go about placing text on the windows desktop? I've been told that GetDesktopWindow() is what I need but I need an example.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is there not already a notification system built into windows that you can use instead of just writing text to the desktop window? hint: There probably is.

Comment: I want to make something like a windows-sidebar. mostly as a learning experience, But I think it would be useful as well...

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming your ultimate goal is displaying some sort of status information on the desktop.

You will have to do either:

- Inject a DLL into Explorer's process and subclass the desktop window (the `SysListView32` at the bottom of the `Progman` window's hierarchy) to paint your text directly onto it.
- Create a nonactivatable window whose background is painted using `PaintDesktop` and paint your text on it.

First solution is the most intrusive, and quite hard to code, so I would not recommend it.

Second solution allows the most flexibility. No "undocumented" or reliance on a specific implementation of Explorer, or even of just having Explorer as a shell.

In order to prevent a window from being brought to the top when clicked, you can use the extended window style `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` on Windows 2000 and up. On downlevel systems, you can handle the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message and return `MA_NOACTIVATE`.

You can get away with the `PaintDesktop` call if you need true transparency by using layered windows, but the concept stays the same. I wrote another answer detailing how to properly do layered windows with alpha using GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just draw the text in the desktop wallpaper image file?

This solution would be feasible if you don't have to update the information too often and if you have a wallpaper image.

One can easily use [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5%28VS.80%29.aspx) class to load the wallpaper image, [CImage::GetDC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23hdhzz%28VS.80%29.aspx) to obtain a device context to draw into, then save the new image, and finally update the desktop wallpaper to the new image.

Comment: I had already thought of that but the data has to be updated frequently.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried but i assume you could do the following:

1. use GetDesktopWindow to retrieve the handle of the desktop window
2. use SetWindowLong to point the windows message handler to your own procedure
3. in your proc, process the WM_PAINT message (or whatever) and draw what you need.
4. in your proc, call the original message handler (as returned by SetWindowLong).

not 100% sure it will work, but seems like it should as this is the normal way to subclass a window.

-don

Comment: That would crash twice: Once when Explorer.EXE fails to call your own procedure (it's in your process, not Explorer). If we could ignore that, it would crash when you'd try to call the original WndProc in Explorer's process, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to produce something like the Sidebar, you probably just want to create one or more [layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#layered).  That will also allow you to process mouse clicks and other normal sources of input, and if you supply the alpha channel information, Windows will make sure that your window is drawn properly at all times.  If you don't want the window to be interactive, use appropriate styles (such as WS_EX_NOACTIVATE) like Koro suggests.